# JQueryMobile dynamically added options not being reflected

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

Using JQM 1.4.5. I'm adding results from a web service and the results are added to the select. If i use `$("#statsSelect")` from my chrome console I can see all the records that were added to my select but the changes are never reflected on the page. If I inspect the element where the select menu is there are only the original options.

Currently I load the html page, then I insert the below select html, then I call ajax for my data, then I insert it using `addStatsTemplate`. The dynamically added options are never shown.

`Main.js` file that loads the below, runs `getAllUsersStats(ajax call)` and passes `addStatTemplates` which is a callback function reference below.

```
$('#statsPage').bind("pageshow",function(){ // When entering pagetwo
    /** Add the stats returned to the select tag **/
    loadStatsPage();
    getAllUsersStats(addStatTemplates);
});
```

My function that is inserting my select html

```
 var targetInsert = '[data-role=content]';
 insertStatsSelect(targetInsert);
 $.get('/forms/CreateStatsForm.html', function (retData) {
     $(targetInsert).append(retData).trigger('create');
 });
```

My Select

```
<div class="ui-field-contain">
  <label for="statsSelect" class="select">Stats:</label>
  <select name="statsSelect" id="statsSelect">
    <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>
    <option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option>
    <option value="express">Express: next day</option>
    <option value="overnight">Overnight</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Function adding the json data to the select

```
/**
 * Add the returned stats to the select tag
 */
function addStatTemplates(data){
    var statsSelect = $('#statsSelect').selectmenu();
    $(statsSelect).empty();
    var f = false;
    $.each(data,function(i, v){
        var sheetname = v.sheetname;
        if(f === false){
            $(statsSelect).append($("<option>").attr("value", v.id).attr("selected", "selected").text(sheetname));
        } else {
            $(statsSelect).append($("<option>").attr("value", v.id).text(sheetname));
        }
        f = true;
    });
    $(statsSelect).selectmenu("refresh", true);
}
```

**things I've tried**

1. Inserting the options just as string like `'<option value="'+id+'">'+sheetname+'</option>'`
2. I have tried using .html() to add instead of append
3. Instead of `var statsSelect = $('#statsSelect').selectmenu();` I have used just `$('#statsSelect')`
4. I have tried adding `$(statsSelect).selectmenu();` then     `$(statsSelect).selectmenu("refresh", true);` after the insert. I have also tried these in console and it does not work
5. I have tried `$('#myPageID').trigger('create');` to recreate the page

I know this question has been run into the ground but I can't seem to figure out why its not showing

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the only way to correctly target the select menu is to use

```
$("html #statsSelect");
```

And place "html" before the id tag. Otherwise it will either create a new select tag somewhere in the DOM and add it to the visible tag but not show the result. amazing...